# user inputs in python giving float, array multiplication issue

Tags: python, numpy

I have following lines of code working fine when inputs given in console:

```
import numpy as np
def simple_exponential_smoothing(actuals, n_forecast_periods,alpha):
    return np.array([np.array([alpha*((1-alpha)**k)*actuals[len(actuals)-k-1] for k in range (len(actuals))]).sum()]*n_forecast_periods)
simple_exponential_smoothing(actuals, n_forecast_periods,alpha)
```

However, it doesn't work when try to get same user inputs in code itself:

```
import numpy as np
actuals = []
actuals = input("Input list:")
n_forecast_periods = int(input("Int:"))
alpha = float(input("float:"))
def simple_exponential_smoothing(actuals, n_forecast_periods,alpha):
    return np.array([np.array([alpha*((1-alpha)**k)*actuals[len(actuals)-k-1] for k in range (len(actuals))]).sum()]*n_forecast_periods)
simple_exponential_smoothing(actuals, n_forecast_periods,alpha)
```

Apologize, if this is not a good question. I am new to Python.

I have already tried using map function for multiplication; too complex for me to use it in following setup.

Comment: You say "It doesn't work". What doesn't work? Do you get an error message? If so, which?

Comment: The first `actuals=[]` doesn't do anything for you.